# Here reverse geocode api error Requested resource not found

Tags: here-api

revgeocode.search.hereapi.com always returns either incorrect credentials or resource not found

https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/%20revgeocode%20?at=48.2181679%2C16.3899064%20&lang=en-US%20&apiKey= with api key returns resource not found

https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=41.8842%2C-87.6388%2C250&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&apiKey= with same api key returns

{
"details": "invalid credentials for ",
"additionalData": [],
"type": "PermissionError",
"subtype": "InvalidCredentials"
}

I created new project with service linked with HERE Search - Reverse Geocoder v7, added app to project and generated new api key to access reversegeocode for locations.

The solution and documentation doesn't match, the simple task is so much complicated and documentation from service linking pointed to v1 which always throws  resource not found error.

Tried even 6.2 with app code and app id , it returns the same error.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove all spaces from url no "%20", "%2c", no new line.
2. go to here platform , project manager and check in services tab that you have liked all the services that you need to your project or not, in your case forward geocoding and reverse geocoding.
3. go to access and permissions of your project and check whether your app has access to your project or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove extra spaces from the url and the API call will work.
https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=48.2181679,16.3899064&lang=en-US&apiKey=

Also note, the Geocoder 6.2 service will not work with API keys generated on HERE Platform and the Appid/Appcode authentication method is deprecated.